# RStudio startup error

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am having problems opening RStudio, it worked fine before I got my mouse pad reconfigured. Here goes... When I open the program, it loads but appears blank. The menu tabs appear but do not populate when clicked. I've read a few answers to this one of which involved deleting the 'RStudio-Desktop' within the local files but did not solve the issue. I managed to run the RStudio diagnostic and below is the error message. OS is Windows 7.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide some insight regarding this.

> Attempting to launch R session...
>   R_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-33~1.1
>    PATH=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64;C:\WINDOWS\Orant\product\11.2.0\client
>   _1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\Syste>m
>   32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C
>   :\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\b
>   in\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\M
>   icrosoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSy
>   stem\
>
> R session launched, attempting to connect on port 44157...
>
> Connected to R session, attempting to initialize...
>
> 13 Oct 2016 16:04:22 [rsession-B859XXXX] ERROR system error 5 (Access is denied)
>   [path=//mshsrmsapppXXXX/B859XXXX$]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::
>   core::FilePath::makeCurrentPath(bool) const C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\c
>   pp\core\FilePath.cpp:978; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) C:\Users\Admi
>   nistrator\rstudio\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:3202
>   QApplication::qAppName: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
>
> C:\Program Files\RStudio>

Thanks,
Mits

Answer (score 0):

Error 5 would suggest that the application is being written to those directories which does not have write privileges.
Make sure those folders have write privileges.

You can also try running RStudio application as Administrator.
To do so, Click on Start -> RStudio ( right click) -> Run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems installing R and RStudio on Windows 8.1 in C:\Program Files. From Vista, Windows places multiple restrictions on systems folders such as `%windir%` and `%ProgramFiles%`.

Uninstall and re-install in a folder where you are not restricted, such as `C:\Apps` or similar. You should hopefully have no further issues.